# How do I select tokens from a string using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select a token out of a string if it exists in the string, I've got as far the following but I'm unsure why it doesn't compile:

```
IList<string> tokens = _animals.Split(';');

Func<string, bool> f1 = str => str.Contains("Dog");
Func<string, Func<string, bool>, string> f2 = str => Equals(f1, true);

var selected = tokens.Select(f2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or in words

```
var selected = from token in tokens where token.Contains("Dog") select token;
```

Comment: Yeah, that does the job too, though I the query syntax is more than what's necessary in this case (a simple call to the Where extension method will do).

Comment: @Noldorin this version is the comprehension syntax version of your solution

Answer (score 5):

I think you just want this.

```
var selected = tokens.Where(str => str.Contains("Dog"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need LINQ to do that?  Why can you do something like this:

```
_animals.Contains("Dog")
```

Comment: No need to make your problem more complicated than it ought to be.  I suggest finding an example more suited to Linq.  Create a list of strings with the names of Presidents (or whoever) and then write a Linq query to pull out all the names starting with "L" or "Wa" or whatever.

Comment: Not sure this is quite what the asker wants, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Its kind of silly to select out a token that you are passing in to see if it exists.  If the string contains the token, why do you need to select it out again?

Comment: It's not quite the same.  The tokens themselves might be delimited strings - (Cat:Tom;Mouse:Jerry;Dog:Rover;Dog:Fido;).  The linq code when then allow him to extract (project) just the names.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var result = (from p in tokens where p.Contains("Dog") select p);
```